# Как написать страницу справки для man-db?

Tags: linux, man

Во всём интернете ни один русский программист не задался этим вопросом. Как написать англоязычную страницу - вопросов нет. А вот когда надо выполнить две операции - "интернационализацию" и "локализацию", неясно, как именно это делать. Ясно, что советуют использовать man-db вместо man. Неясно откуда брать названия локалей и куда их вписывать - в имя файла между названием утилиты и номером секции mytool.ru-RU.1 или складывать в отдельные директории, например ru-RU/mytool.1
А если сделать вторым способом, то как с этими директориями справится пакетный менеджер дистрибутива при установке? На примере portage - мне что, для каждого языка при пакетировании писать отдельную команду установки, потому что директории у языков разные?

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос, пожалуйста. // и уточните, при чём тут программа *linux*. вы для неё документацию пишете?

Comment: да, подскажите, пожалуйста, куда пожаловаться на этого тролля. Вопрос конкретен, а линукс тут настолько при всём, что сложно даже прокомментировать - https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/ А троллит он меня не в первый раз.

Comment: 1. если вы считаете комментарий оскорбительным, отметьте его тревогой, пожалуйста. 2. из текста вашего вопроса, действительно, не было понятно, что вы пишете справку для программы *linux*. теперь стало понятно. спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Пишу документацию в AsciiDoc, в т.ч. на русском в UTF-8. Для конвертации в man-pages использую a2x: http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/chunked/ch24.html, единственно, добавляю опцию `-L`.

После чего помещаете файл в /usr/share/man/ru/manНОМЕР_СЕКЦИИ/ и радуетесь жизни.

Пример исходника:

```
ASCIIDOC_TEST(1)
================

NAME
----

asciidoc_test - Простой пример документации на русском языке для man

DESCRIPTION
-----------

В исходной asciidoc документации обязательны следующие секции:

  TITLE:: представляет собой заголовок первого уровня вида ИМЯ_СТРАНИЦЫ(НОМЕР_СЕКЦИИ): ASCIIDOC_TEST(1)
  NAME:: заголовок второго уровня, секция должна состоять из одного параграфа в котором, через запятую
           перечислены сущности, после чего идёт дефис и описание.
  SYNOPSIS или DESCRIPTION:: заголовок второго уровня, тут уже пишите что хотите. Должна быть как минимум одна,
         а могут быть и обе.
```

"Компилируем":

```
a2x -L --doctype manpage --format manpage asciidoc_test.adoc
```

"Инсталлируем":

```
sudo cp asciidoc_test.1 /usr/share/man/ru/man1/
```

Пробуем:

```
man asciidoc_test
```

Наблюдаем что-то вроде:

```
ASCIIDOC_TEST(1)                                                                                                                                                                             ASCIIDOC_TEST(1)

NAME
       asciidoc_test - Простой пример документации на русском языке для man

DESCRIPTION
       В исходной asciidoc документации обязательны следующие секции:

       TITLE
           представляет собой заголовок первого уровня вида ИМЯ_СТРАНИЦЫ(НОМЕР_СЕКЦИИ): ASCIIDOC_TEST(1)

       NAME
           заголовок второго уровня, секция должна состоять из одного параграфа в котором, через запятую перечислены сущности, после чего идёт дефис и описание.

       SYNOPSIS или DESCRIPTION
           заголовок второго уровня, тут уже пишите что хотите. Должна быть как минимум одна, а могут быть и обе.

                                                                                                  09/10/2015                                                                                 ASCIIDOC_TEST(1)
 Manual page asciidoc_test(1) line 1/22 (END) (press h for help or q to quit)
```

А по поводу как точно должен выглядеть путь, читается в `man man`, выдержка есть тут: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43399

```
   International support is available with this package.   Native  lan‐
   guage  manual pages are accessible (if available on your system) via
   use of locale functions.  To activate such support, it is  necessary
   to  set either $LC_MESSAGES, $LANG or another system dependent envi‐
   ronment variable to your language locale, usually specified  in  the
   POSIX 1003.1 based format:

   <language>[_<territory>[.<character-set>[,<version>]]]

   If  the  desired  page  is available in your locale, it will be dis‐
   played in lieu of the standard (usually American English) page.
```

Более информативно тут: http://www.sbras.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/unix-man?man+1:

```
 By default, man searches for a localized manpage in a set of
 locale subdirectories of each manpath(1) component.

 Locale name is taken from the first of three environment
 variables with a nonempty value: LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, or LANG,
 in the specified order.

 If the value could not be determined, or is not a valid
 locale name, then only non-localized manpage will be looked
 up.

 Otherwise, man will search in the following subdirectories,
 in the order of precedence:

       <lang>_<country>.<charset>
       <lang>.<charset>
       en.<charset>

 For example, for ``de_DE.ISO8859-1'' locale, man will search
 in the following subdirectories of the /usr/share/man manpath
 component:

       /usr/share/man/de_DE.ISO8859-1
       /usr/share/man/de.ISO8859-1
       /usr/share/man/en.ISO8859-1

 Finally, if the search of localized manpage fails, it will be
 looked up in the default /usr/share/man directory.
```